# Aligning chart title with left side of numbers on the y axis

Tags: vega-lite, altair

I am trying to make an Altair theme that conforms with our internal guidelines. I found this excellent [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/consistently-beautiful-visualizations-with-altair-themes-c7f9f889602) that solved most of my issues. However, neither the article nor a search of the documentation has solved the problem of aligning the chart title with the left side of the numbers on the y axis.
[See the dotted line in Urban institute's theme for visual explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dMer.png).
The problem is that I do not know the width of the longest number on the y axis. The solutions I have found just hard code an offset for the expected width of the number. However, I have to make a theme that automatically conforms to the standard in all cases.
Hints to possible solutions are welcome. I will try them out and post results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The available title alignment settings for Altair/Vega-Lite are listed here: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/title.html#params

The closest thing to what you desire is to set `anchor='start'` in the title config:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
cars = data.cars()

alt.Chart(cars).mark_bar().encode(
  x=alt.X('Miles_per_Gallon', bin=True),
  y='count()',
).properties(
    title='A bar chart'
).configure_title(
    anchor='start'
)
```

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no way in the Vega-Lite schema to control the alignment more finely than that. If this is important to your use of Altair/Vega-Lite, I would suggest opening a [Vega-Lite feature request](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/new?labels=Feature+Request+%3Araising_hand_woman%3A&template=Feature_request.md).

Comment: Thank you. It is good to know that there are not any easy solutions I have missed. Altair is easy to use and pretty good at achieving the right look, so I might just use the manual offset. I have not found any other library that makes it easy to make this alignment. Thank you for your work on Altair Jake.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this exactly what you're looking for since you mentioned wanting to create a theme, but you can recreate the look of the UI theme by adding text to your chart via mark_text().

Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0,1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':[0,1,2,3,4,5]})
text_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0], 'col2':[0], 'col3':['title']})

line = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(x='col1', y='col2')
text = alt.Chart(text_df.query('col1 == 0')).mark_text(dx=-60, dy=-400, fontSize=24, font='Lato').encode(x='col1', y='col2', text='col3')
line + text
```

This is the resulting chart:

[image]